# SQL to divide two negative values in the column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting different result when I try to get the percentage calculation through sql.

```
 ROUND( 100 * (  Col2   /  ( Col1 +   Col2)))
```

output

```
col1     col2      colR
-----    -----     ------
150       51       34
-400.11  -160.04   40
```

when it divides two negative values it gives as 40 instead of 29. To cross check I wrote this query

```
   select round( 100* ( -160.04/-560.15 ) ) from dual;
```

and it works perfect I get 29.

My question is:

1. how should I modify my query in-order to accompany the negative values.
2. whats wrong in this query, why doesn't oracle able to query properly.

Edit:

My bad, I made a typo error and came to this conclusion. How do I close this question?

Comment: What are Col1 and Col2 datatypes?

Comment: @davidmontoyago both are NUMBER

Comment: you are getting the wrong answer when it is not a negative number as well. It appears as if your formula is only dividing by column 1. Check your use of parentheses and your actual spelling (since I assume your columns aren't really named col1 and col2).

Comment: I agree with HLGM. [This fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8b2c/1) proves that there is nothing wrong with Oracle. Most likely you didn't show us your real query.

Comment: @jero: you can vote to delete/close the question or simply answer your own question and mark it as answered (you may accept your own answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you expect this results:

```
  ROUND( 100 * (  Col2   /  ( ABS(Col1) +   ABS(Col2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

per @HLGEM's comment above...

In SQL Server, given the following:

```
create table #foo
(
  c1      float not null ,
  c2      float not null ,
  c1c2sum as c1 + c2     ,
  cR      as round( 100.0 * c2 / (c1+c2) , 0 ) ,
  cX      as round( 100.0 * c2 /  c1     , 0 ) ,
)

insert #foo (c1,c2) values( 150     , 51      )
insert #foo (c1,c2) values( -400.11 , -160.04 )
```

Executing:

```
select * from #foo
```

yields the following result set:

```
c1      c2      c1c2sum cR cX
------- ------  ------- -- --
150     51      201     25 34
-400.11 -160.04 -560.15 29 40
```

I suspect you've got a parenthetical problem, so to speak.